# Generating dependency graph of Autotools packages

Tags: graph, dependencies, autotools

I have a software system having 30+ Open Source packages, most of them using GNU Autotools suite.

Are there tools to automatically generate package-to-package dependency graph? I.e. I'd like to see something like gst-plugins-good -> gst-plugins-base -> gstreamer -> glib.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you could probably whip something together with this knowledge:

- Scan the file named either `configure.ac` or `configure.in` in the package's root directory.
- Look for a string of the form `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([...],[...]...)`
- The second argument of that macro consists of package requirements of the form `package` or `package >= version` separated by whitespace.
- The `requirement` string might not be the same as the package tarball name; a tarball that contains `package.pc` or `package.pc.in` provides the package `package`.
- This only works for dependencies that use pkg-config. Some don't and you'll need to keep track of those dependencies by hand.

Comment: Rather than scanning by hand, you can also generate useful data with something like: autoconf --trace=AC_CHECK_LIB:'$1:$4' --trace=PKG_CHECK_MODULES:'$1:$2' --trace=AC_SEARCH_LIBS:'$2:$4'

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, because this is a hard problem. If there were only one way to build a package, it might not be too bad, but in general this isn't the case.  You have the `--enable-foo` and `--with-foo` options that you can pass into `configure`. Those are sometimes package dependent also, requiring more packages.  Most Linux distros (I think but am not completely sure) maintain these sort of dependency lists for `yum` or `zypper` or `apt` or whatever the package manager is by hand, and only one layer deep, leaving it up to the package manager to traverse the graph. The packages for the distro are only built *one* way. It's not unusual for these lists to be broken, also.